# How to get the number of days in a month in Rust?

Tags: rust

Is there a idiomatic Rust way to get the number of days in a given month? I've looked at chrono but I haven't found anything in the docs for this.

I'm looking for something that can manage leap years similar to `calendar.monthrange` in Python or `DateTime.DaysInMonth` in C# .

Comment: *"would the best next step be to create a calendar crate or something of the sort?"* -- Would be overkill if this is the only functionality you need. It's a fairly trivial function to write, have you tried it? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm) even has the algorithm for determining if it's a leap year in pseudocode.

Comment: What I'm really looking for is a high level API for managing datetime for time series analysis. Getting the number of days in a months is only the first baby step.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`NaiveDate::signed_duration_since`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4/chrono/naive/struct.NaiveDate.html#method.signed_duration_since) from the [`chrono` crate](https://crates.io/crates/chrono):

```
use chrono::NaiveDate;

fn main() {
    let year = 2018;
    for (m, d) in (1..=12).map(|m| {
        (
            m,
            if m == 12 {
                NaiveDate::from_ymd(year + 1, 1, 1)
            } else {
                NaiveDate::from_ymd(year, m + 1, 1)
            }.signed_duration_since(NaiveDate::from_ymd(year, m, 1))
            .num_days(),
        )
    }) {
        println!("days {} in month {}", d, m);
    }
}
```

Comment: it's work thank you

Answer (score 11):

```
pub fn get_days_from_month(year: i32, month: u32) -> i64 {
    NaiveDate::from_ymd(
        match month {
            12 => year + 1,
            _ => year,
        },
        match month {
            12 => 1,
            _ => month + 1,
        },
        1,
    )
    .signed_duration_since(NaiveDate::from_ymd(year, month, 1))
    .num_days()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Additionally, it would be good to explain what *this* answer brings as compared to the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53687279/155423). They both appear to use the same logic and functions.